# podman "Error: cannot open sd-bus: No such file or directory: OCI not found" error. Dietpi, raspberry pi3b

Tags: server, raspberry-pi3, podman

AFter installing podman on my pi3b using:

```
    sudo apt-get -y install podman
```

After that i updated and rebooted, now when I try to run:

```
sudo podman run hello-world
```

it gives me the following error:

```
Error: cannot open sd-bus: No such file or directory: OCI not found
```

Running all this as root.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: This is probably something to do with your systemd setup on that machine. This bug-report might point you in the right direction. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1768954